# WiFi без доступа к интернету

Tags: android

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой, при подключенном WiFi доступа к интернету нет. Как проверить именно доступ к интернету?

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    wifiInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    wifiInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Такая проверка говорит что доступ есть, хотя это не так.(подключена сеть WiFi без доступа к интернету)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть только один способ проверить наличие интернета - что то скачать с него. Та же винда, когда появляется сеть, вначале рисует значек с желтым треугольником "соедиенение есть, но без подключения к интернету". Потом пытается с сайта майкрософта скачать текстовый файлик. Если это удается - интернет есть.

В современном мире понятие "есть интернет" очень расплывчато. Например, в России. Вроде и интернет есть, а половина ресурсов заблокирована РосКомНадзором. Так как телефон/комп не знает, к каким именно ресурсам Вы хотите обращаться - он не знает, есть ли инернет "с Вашей точки зрения".

Я помню, как несколько лет назад слег Вконтакте. И пару дней он был недоступен. Сотни пользователей интернета звонили провайдерам, угрожая судом, мол "нет интернета, за что мы пллатим?". А со стороны провайдера не понимали, все ведь работает. Подумаешь, Вконтакт прилег.

Поэтому, если Вам нужно знать "доступен ли интернет", скорее всего Вам нужно знать "доступен ли определенный сайт(ы)". Поэтому, после того, как появилась сеть (проверенная кодом в вопросе), просто попробуйте обратиться к своему сайту. Но даже если Ваш сайт слег, не пишите пользователю "нет интернета", пишите "сайт Дмитрия недоступен, возможно у Вас нет подключения к интернету?"

Comment: Спасибо. доступно